# IIS10 - MySQL Database Disconnection - An unhandled exception has occurred ( Event id 1309 )

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, iis

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Levfz.jpg)

Hi,
     I'm Getting the below error message and could not able the site. after restarting the IIS site gets reconnected.Please let me Know the Solution for the error.

> Log Name:      Application
>
> Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
>
> Date:          28-06-2019 10:55:30 AM
>
> Event ID:      1309
>
> Task Category: Web Event
>
> Level:         Warning
>
> Keywords:      Classic
>
> User:          N/A
>
> Computer:      PSPINTRANETSVR.root.com
>
> Description:
>
> Event code: 3005
>
> Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
>
> Event time: 28-06-2019 10:55:30
>
> Event time (UTC): 28-06-2019 05:25:30
>
> Event ID: `c8f21b66d0f6484ea19410b52b9d4f50`
>
> Event sequence: 509
>
> Event occurrence: 4
>
> Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132061709909075750 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: / 
>       Application Path: D:\IIS\PIMS WEBINTERFACE\www\ 
>       Machine name: PSPINTRANETSVR    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 4736 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: IIS APPPOOL\WEBINTERFACE    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
>       Exception message: Connection must be valid and open    Request information: 
>       Request URL: http://site 
>       Request path: /
>       User host address: 000.000.0.000 
>       User:
>       Is authenticated: False 
>       Authentication Type:
>       Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\WEBINTERFACE    Thread information: 
>       Thread ID: 9 
>       Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\WEBINTERFACE 
>       Is impersonating: False 
>       Stack trace:    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
>   at _Application._application.get_department() in
>   D:\Working Folder\Working
>   Projects\Application\new\Application\Application\database.cs:line
>   101    at Application.pims.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in D:\Working Folder\Working
>   Projects\Application\new\Application\Application\pims.Master.cs:line
>   40    at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp,
>   Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>       Custom event details:
>
> Event Xml: 
>   
>       
>       1309
>       3
>       3
>       0x80000000000000
>       
>       4137
>       Application
>       PSPINTRANETSVR.root.com
>             
>       3005
>       An unhandled exception has occurred.
>       28-06-2019 10:55:30
>       28-06-2019 05:25:30
>       c8f21b66d0f6484ea19410b52b9d4f50
>       509
>       4
>       0
>       /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132061709909075750
>       Full
>       /
>       D:\IIS\PIMS WEBINTERFACE\www\
>       PSPINTRANETSVR
>       
>       
>       4736
>       w3wp.exe
>       IIS APPPOOL\WEBINTERFACE
>       InvalidOperationException
>       Connection must be valid and open
>       http://site/
>       /project_complete.aspx
>       192.168.0.000
>       
>       
>       False
>       
>       
>       IIS APPPOOL\WEBINTERFACE
>       9
>       IIS APPPOOL\WEBINTERFACE
>       False
>          at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
>   at Application.application.get_department() in
>   D:\Working Folder\Working
>   Projects\Application\new_Application\Application\database.cs:line
>   101    at Application.pims.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in D:\Working Folder\Working
>   Projects\Application\new\Application\Application\Master.cs:line
>   40    at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp,
>   Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour], then reading [ask]. Just pasting an exception without any context, introductory text or even a question makes it hard / impossible for others to help you.

Comment: Exception traces contains useful informations. Just read them. _What happens here: D:\Working Folder\Working Projects\Application\new\Application\Application\database.cs:line 101_

Comment: Ow come on @Diado! Are you not able to reverse engineer his code base with just an exception message?!?
OP, you try to read from a database without having a proper connection to the database: `Exception message: Connection must be valid and open`.

Comment: @Antoine I spend enough of my day job being asked to do similar things by other teams, so no :-p haha

Comment: this could be due to your application pool account .

Comment: But how can i get rid from it @sayahimad

Comment: @AdwaithAishu you can use an udl file to check your connectivity using the same account in the application .

Comment: @sayahimad Coding wise no problem and connection also very well.its working good in old server we was change the server recently then only this problem occurs.

Comment: @sayahimad Its working fine but some times the connection last so we restart the site in IIS server then its works. but its occurs frequently.restarting the server is not a permanent solution that's why we ask

Comment: " you can use an udl file to check your connectivity using the same account in the application " kindly tell the steps for how to check this @sayahimad

Comment: @AdwaithAishu you will find below a link containing all the steps to create an udl file https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem solved by increasing the value of max_connections in MySQL

1.Check how many users connected your Database

```
 show status like 'max_used_connections';
```

2.Check your default max connection range

```
show variables like 'max_connections';
```

3.Set the max connection value whatever you want but the max range is 100000

```
set global max_connections = 100000;
```